# UnitySendMessage doesn't work on iOS

Tags: ios, plugins, unity-game-engine

I was trying to send some data using UnitySendMessage in iOS plugin, but it seem like it doesn't do anything, i don't see any errors and response. I checked function where UnitySendMessage is located, and i'm 100% sure that it starts.

```
- (void) callback{
NSLog(@"UNITY test callback"); 
UnitySendMessage("PluginTest", "listener", "test callback");
}
```

On scene i have gameObject named PluginTest with pluginListener component which contains method:

```
public void listener(string parameter)
{
    print(parameter);
}
```

I also added to UnityAppController.mm this line, which was recommended to add in some post:

```
extern void UnitySendMessage(const char *, const char *, const char *);
```

I have no idea what i'm doing wrong, unitySendMessage seems like it should work without much effort. 
Any help will be appreciated